# Who started the other fight club chapter?

Tags: fight-club

In Fight Club, there's a scene where Tyler Durden and the Narrator are discussing new fight club chapters, and there's one where they both deny starting it, and claim to have thought the other started it. I see three main interpretations of this scene:

1. The straight forward one: some other member of Fight Club started another chapter.
2. Tyler Durden started the chapter, but was messing with the Narrator's head.
3. There's actually a third personality that neither Tyler nor the Narrator is aware of.

Which is most likely the answer, based on actions by Tyler and the Narrator in the movie?  If anyone can also cite book sources, I'll take that too.

Comment: "Which do you think is most likely?" Makes this sound like an opinion question, which is considered off topic here... Now that being said, I don't think this is specifically a bad question, it just needs some rewording. If you reword the question to ask for a more definitive answer backed up by evidence, either through further clues in the movie, or if it was further discussed in the book; I think this would be a much more valid question.

Answer (score 6):

It seems pretty clear that it was **Tyler**. It's possible that some of these chapters were self-starting but Tyler often kept the Narrator in the dark, even lying to him whenever he wants... but the the [**script**](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Fight-Club.html) has the Narrator (called "Jack" in the script) say..

> Every city I went to...
>
> ...as soon as I set foot off the plane..
>
> ...I knew fight club was close.
>
> **Tyler was setting up franchises**, all over the country.

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club) seems to confirm..

> Seeking Tyler, he begins to discover that **Tyler has established a secretive underground network of fight clubs nationwide** operating under the ethos of Project Mayhem.

The denial you refer to..

> ```
>                         JACK
>             Local 8 just started in Penns Grove.
>             And, Bob said he was at fight club in
>             Newcastle last week.
>
>                         TYLER
>             Newcastle?  Did you start that one?
>
>                         JACK
>             I thought you did.
> ```

...is, perhaps, the first indication, in hindsight, that Tyler **is** the Narrator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to remind you one thing/scene here(couldn't find the web link for scene but will edit with timing of the scene).

Remember Narrator gets angry when he came to know about **Project Mayhem** and argues with Tyler that he din't inform and din't make Narrator a part of the project. In reply Tyler says he tried to help him but he's not hitting the bottom as Tyler wanted, so Tyler alone taking care of **Project Mayhem** without Narrator intervention. And **Project Mayhem requires franchises all over the country**. Tyler started franchising when Narrator is asleep(without letting him know).

So I agree with your second point but in different way i.e *Tyler Durden started the chapter without letting his host know so that he could achieve something's his host could never and he doesn't want in anyway that his Host destroys the actual plan at same time teaching Host what really it's all about.*